# LinkedList Hangman

Tags: java, list

For the assignment, we had to create a working version of Hangman using both Arrays and LinkedLists. I completed the Array version, and now must do the LinkedList version. However, I am very unfamiliar with LinkedLists and have no idea where to start. I made a LLCharacterClass which basically creates the chain, and allows the user to add onto it, but now in the main class, I don't know where to start for creating this game.

```
package hangman;

public class LinkedListGameModel implements GameModel {

private int state=0;
private int count=0;
private LLCharacterNode start;
private LLCharacterNode end;

public LinkedListGameModel(String guessWord)
{
    state=STARTING_STATE;
    start=null;
    end=null;

}
@Override
public boolean isPriorGuess(char guess) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public int numberOfGuesses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean isCorrectGuess(char guess) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean doMove(char guess) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean inWinningState() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean inLosingState() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getState() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String previousGuessString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getWord() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

I would just like a starting point or any input on whether I need to add new methods, or anything else. Thank you for any help. PLEASE NO CODE. Just some advice on where to start and how to make this game.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, I would start by initializing your start and end variables. After that, start going through the provided skeleton methods to see what needs to be implemented.

If you're having trouble thinking about what the linked list looks like, you can go [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html) for a better grasp.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer.